# WebApi Mediatypeformatter Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am getting an error and I can't figure out how to solve this. Can anyone help?

> "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is
>   not supported for this resource.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'CrudModel'
>   from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
>   "StackTrace": "   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable'1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable'1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"

WebApiConfig.cs

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );

 EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
 config.EnableCors(cors);
```

On my controller.cs I have the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("InsertCrudApp")]
public HttpResponseMessage InsertValuesCurd([FromBody]CrudModel Insertvalues)
{
    CrudModel objCrudModel = new CrudModel();
    objCrudModel.CrudInsertApp();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

On my Model.cs I have the following code:

```
public bool CrudInsertApp()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetSqlConnection());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_insert_CrudApp", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", this.FirstName.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", this.LastName.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", this.Position.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", this.Status);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", this.Company.ToString());
    int insertResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    if (insertResult > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
 }
```

Comment: How you post? Show javascript code.

Comment: i used postman to test my api